# Google Maps API - All markers don't appear on first load

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need all of the markers to appear on the map on the first load AND the first marker that loads (blue one with shadow) to have an infoWindow that opens on first click. Any helpful suggestions? here's what it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/robzor2014/ye3x8/35/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
initialize();

$("#link1").click(function () {
    changeMarkerPos(38.571924, -122.555494);
    makeMarker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.571924, -122.555494),
        title: 'Clos Pegase',
        content: '<div style="height:150px; width:350px;"><img style="float:right;"src="http://www.clospegase.com/static/images/closPegaseMap.jpg"><h2>Clos Pegase</h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>',
        icon: 'http://www.clospegase.com/static/images/pegase.png'
    });
    makeMarker.open(map, marker);
});

$("#link2").click(function () {
    changeMarkerPos(38.40411, -122.36469);
    makeMarker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.40411, -122.36469),
        title: 'Girard',
        icon: 'http://www.clospegase.com/static/images/girard.png',
        content: '<div style="height:150px; width:350px;"><img style="float:right;"src="http://www.clospegase.com/static/images/closPegaseMap.jpg"><h2>Girard</h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<div>'
    });
    makeMarker.setMap(map);
});

$("#link3").click(function () {
    changeMarkerPos(38.29186, -122.45804);
    makeMarker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.29186, -122.45804),
        title: 'Kunde',
        icon: 'http://www.clospegase.com/static/images/kunde.png',
        content: '<div style="height:150px; width:350px;"><img style="float:right;"src="http://www.clospegase.com/static/images/closPegaseMap.jpg"><h2>Kunde</h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<div>'
    });
});

$("#link4").click(function () {
    changeMarkerPos(38.41461, -122.54650);
    makeMarker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.41461, -122.54650),
        title: 'Viansa',
        icon: 'http://www.clospegase.com/static/images/viansa.png',
        content: '<div style="height:150px; width:350px;"><img style="float:right;"src="http://www.clospegase.com/static/images/closPegaseMap.jpg"><h2>Viansa</h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<div>'
    });
});

function initialize() {

    var styles = [{
        stylers: [{
            saturation: -100
        }]
    }];

    var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
        name: "Styled Map"
    });

    var mapProp = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.571924, -122.555494),
        zoom: 10,
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        streetViewControl: true,
        overviewMapControl: false,
        rotateControl: true,
        scrollwheel: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapProp);

    map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
    map.setMapTypeId('map_style')

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.571924, -122.555494),
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title: 'Clos Pegase',

        icon: 'http://www.clospegase.com/static/images/main.png'
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
    map.panTo(marker.position);


    $()
}

function changeMarkerPos(lat, lon) {
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon)
    marker.setPosition(myLatLng);
    map.panTo(myLatLng);
}

function makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);

    });
}


var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markerArray = [];

function makeMarker(options) {
    var pushPin = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map
    });
    pushPin.setOptions(options);
    google.maps.event.addListener(pushPin, 'click', function () {
        infoWindow.setOptions(options);
        infoWindow.open(map, pushPin);
    });
    markerArray.push(pushPin);
    return pushPin;
}
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function () {
    infoWindow.close();
});

function openMarker(i) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(markerArray[i], 'click');
};

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only adding one marker to the map initially:

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.571924, -122.555494),
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    title: 'Clos Pegase',

    icon: 'http://www.clospegase.com/static/images/main.png'
});

marker.setMap(map);
map.panTo(marker.position);
```

The other markers only get added when you click on the link (which also adds the infowindow functionality you are looking for):

```
$("#link2").click(function () {
    changeMarkerPos(38.40411, -122.36469);
    makeMarker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.40411, -122.36469),
        title: 'Girard',
        icon: 'http://www.clospegase.com/static/images/girard.png',
        content: '<div style="height:150px; width:350px;"><img style="float:right;"src="http://www.clospegase.com/static/images/closPegaseMap.jpg"><h2>Girard</h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<div>'
    });
    makeMarker.setMap(map);
});
```

Comment: How can get all of the tabs to show up on first load without losing any of the functionality? I'm new to Java and am gonna need you to spell this out for me if possible. Thanks for your response!

Comment: This is javascript, not Java.  Perhaps you should look for a working example that exhibits the functionality you want, there are many on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the language. I have looked for working examples that exhibit the functionality I'm looking for, but have yet to find  any that are implementing all of the functionality I need in one map. Which is why Ive posted this question. Thanks for your response though.